# Wi-Fi is not working since installing Nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my mobile workstation. I installed the most recent NVIDIA drivers with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535` and the CUDA toolkits I need for my TensorFlow version. I hope you can help me with troubleshooting the problem that my Wi-Fi is not working anymore.

My Software & Updates app shows:

[image: Additional Drivers],

When I type `sudo lshw -C Network` in the terminal I get:

```
*-network:0 UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Tiger Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:629119c000-629119ffff
```

When I type `modinfo iwlwifi` I get:

[image: get]

so it looks to me that the drivers are there.

I did a couple of things that I found on Stack Exchange such as:

1. Changing the entries in /etc/apt/sources.list from the local to the global address, purging the driver (`sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-535` and `sudo apt autoremove` and `sudo apt autoclean`) and reinstalling the drivers with `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` .
2. Booting in the GRUB menu in the previous kernel version, but wifi did not work there either.
3. Typed into the terminal `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` with the output:

   [image: output]
4. Typed into the terminal `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and got:

   [image: get]
5. Typed into the terminal "ls /etc/modprobe.d/" and got:

   [image: get]